# 38999 contacts for pcb through-hole pass through connectors

Tags: connector, components, contact

So I'm working on a board that will act as a pass-through for a m/f pair of connectors interjecting to trace off some of the contacts to connect to another device for monitoring the signals. We did something similar for another project and the following image shows what I'm trying to find. I've found the right side's contact is called "PC Tail contacts" but I've been through like 500 pages of catalogs trying to find the contact on the left. Does anyone know what this contact is called and maybe where I can order them?

[image]

The right pins are going to get soldered to the board in through-holes and then the other connector will mate with the rest sticking out creating the pass-through for the two connectors. Any help would be appreciated as I've spent way too much time googling this and digging through catalogs.

Comment: How many pins in that connector? Do you have the outer shell part number?

Comment: It's the G41's (also called 21-41's depending on the manufacturer you talk to). The connector doesn't matter though. The contact is a size 20 and so any other connector that uses size 20, like the ones we're going to be using, can use the same pins. The problem is that I'm not going to have enough just pulling them out of this one so I need to order more and have no idea where to find them.

Comment: Contact Amphenol. They should be able to give you a part # that you can order from Digikey, Mouser, who ever their distributor is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contacts are actually [Pin Receptacle Connector 0.025" ~ 0.037" (0.64mm ~ 0.94mm) Standard Tail Solder](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/0309-2-15-15-47-27-10-0/ED10355-ND/433562) and made by mill-max for anyone who stumbles across this. The idea is to solder the ones with tails and then connector pin receptacle contacts mate with them to create a pass-through that can T off to some other circuitry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a "solder mounting receptale"

http://www.amphenol-aerospace.com/pdf/catalogs/D38999_I_II_section.pdf

Work thru the steps, then call tech support.

Are you sure you wouldn't rather go with something like a PCB mountable Dsub connector. Would be a lot cheaper. Example:

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1-5747301-4/A121605-ND/2135483

Comment: We were going to go with Dsub connectors but the boss _has to **have**_ the military connectors because he like the way they look. "Solder mounting receptacle" looks like what I found where the back of the contacts has solder cups. What I'm looking for is more of just a pin and socket mating so the pins can be soldered through the pcb and the other connector will be mounted to the case's cover and will mate to the pins when you put the cover on completing the pass-through for the connectors. If you just imaging mating the back of those connectors in the picture and sticking a board between it.

Comment: What will the outer connect mate with physically then?  Need the shell for stability and to line up the pins.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a "connector saver" contact arrangement. Maybe that will help.

Comment: That looks like it might be the right path... made by Glenair, right? I'll have to dig through their catalog and see about their contacts because the socket part has to be smaller to match the size of the pc tails and not the same size contact.